# How to connect to mysql using vba in excel 2007

Tags: mysql, vba

I have used the code bellow to connect to mysql and I have install mysql odbc connector version 5.3.

```
'Connect to database
Function CnnOpen(ByVal ServerName As String, ByVal DBName As String, _
ByVal TblName As String, ByVal User As String, ByVal PWD As String)

    Dim CnnStr As String
    Set Cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Cnn.CommandTimeout = 15
    CnnStr = "DRIVER = {MySql ODBC 5.3 Driver}; SERVER =" & ServerName & _
             "; Database =" & DBName & "; USER =" & User & "; PASSWORD =" _
             & PWD & "; Option=3"
    Cnn.ConnectionString = CnnStr
    Cnn.Open
End Function
```

I have the following error:

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]Data source name not found and
>   no default driver specified

Is there any incorrect connection string or any mistake in the code? Please, help.

Comment: Since I can't test to know for sure, I'll put it as comment:

### CnnStr = "DRIVER = {MySql ODBC 5.3 Driver}; SERVER =" & ServerName & "; Database =" & DBName & "; USER =" & User & "; PASSWORD =" & PWD & "; Option=3" ###

When connecting to a remote SQL database in python, I had a similar error, which was resolved by removing the spaces. From http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/ , you can see that there are no spaces. Try changing that first

Comment: Have you installed the MySQL ODBC driver? Go into ODBC Administrator (the 32 bit one) and create a _file_ dsn and test it. Then open that file and you should find a string approximating what you need in your connection string above.

Comment: I am trying to connect to my database website.

Comment: I am trying to connect to my website database. I have tried testing the connection using ODBC Administrator, I always have a Connection failed message "[MYSQL][odbc 5.3(w) Driver]Host'myhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server:

Bellow is the input:

TCP/IP Server: the IP of my websit (I used this ip to log into phpmyadmin which works just fine)
User: root
Password: mypassword

Is there anything I did wrong? Please, help.